# Django admin not loading

Tags: django

I have a problem with Django admin. I can login and so on but I have way to create company profiles to Django and display them on website.

When I want to edit some profile in the admin page from my browser, it shows:

> net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Only browser that opens the page is Microsoft Edge.

I am not a developer, so I will try my best to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Sorry. The question is how to fix it, so I could edit these profiles in django admin again (that chrome loads these profiles).